# How to read "modulo" (Math) in German? About the preposition it induces

Tags: preposition, mathematics

In English there exists the [proposition *modulo*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/meaning-of-modulo-the-fact) (see also the [Wiktionary entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modulo#Preposition)) or *modulo the fact*. Any of these, however, are not proper from English, but have their origin in mathematics, presumably from the expression[`p≡q mod n`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_mit_Rest#Modulo).
Parenthetically, the fact

> 6 ≡ 2 (mod 4)

is extended to more general (i.e. non-mathematical situations), where you can say:

> All mammals, modulo the monotremes, give birth to live young. (Example taken from Wiktionary's link above).

Now to the actual question, which is constrained to math. In German one uses the same sign, *`mod`* or `X/Y` for *X mod Y*. While usual expressions involve only mathematical objects, one usually needs to write them down with words (here is where the question might be valid here). That is, it turns out that in concrete cases, when the involved expressions have a proper name, it doesn't sound too educated if one mentions the letters. Let me bore you with a last line specifying that:

> **Examples:**
>
> 1. Consider **F/Σ<sub>n</sub>** where *Σ<sub>n</sub>* has a proper name, *die symmetrische Gruppe*. If you want to read out or write down that in German, then *modulo* should be a preposition. I'd read it as:
>    "*ef modulo der symmetrischen Gruppe*"
> 2. Consider **a≡b mod n**, where *a,b,n* are just numbers. Then after some lines it's valid to state that as:
>    "*[hier erwähnt man **n**]...und modulo diese(r) Zahl, ist a gleich b*"

Which case should I use for *modulo*? (I'm going with genitive because of the answer given [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-is-german-really-loosing-genitiv-evoluti), but I'd need help from an expert.)

Comment: Note that in German, „a gleicht b“ is not the same as „a ist gleich b“. „a gleicht b“ is more like „a is similar to b“. There is no direct correspondence to „a equals b“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz "a equals b" (a=b) is exactly the same as "a ist gleich b". But the usage of `=` is wrong here in all cases. It's about congruence which is written using the triple bar sign: ≡ (u+2261) (according to DIN1302).

Comment: @Toscho That would be my fault. But it actually isn't, because it's kind of hard to type in LaTeX in GLU ;) Anyway everybody would understand with a `=`, with a `~`, with what appears in LaTeX for `\simeq`, etc. Thanks for finding the sign.

Comment: @Toscho, I should have been clearer. I wanted to say that there is no translation of “a equals b” that preserves the structure of the original, i.e. is of the form „a [Verb] b“.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ahja, das stimmt natürlich.

Comment: @c.p. Apart from the commonly known "Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list" you could also use `unimath-symbols.pdf`, which is part of the documentation of the `fontspec` package used for unicode based engines like `xetex` or `luatex`. It shows the signs, latex-macros, descriptions and unicode points.

Comment: BTW: The wikipedia example is utter crap. `modulo` is misused for `except for`, which is set theoretic difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both algebraical constructs can be expressed using `modulo`.

**Factorized constructs** like $F/\sigma_n$ are read

- `F durch die symmetrische Gruppe` or
- `F (faktorisiert) nach der symmetrischen Gruppe` or
- `F modulo symmetrische Gruppe` or
- `F modulo der symmetrischen Gruppe` (I haven't heard anybody say `F modulo die symmetrische Gruppe` but I wouldn't even bother if I did.)

So in this case `modulo` is a preposition demanding **genitive** (, nominative) or a **special construct** used as part of an attribute.

**Equality inside factorized constructs** like $a\equiv b mod m$ is read

- `a ist kongruent (zu) b modulo m`

So in this case `modulo` is a preposition as well but used as part of an adverb. If used with single variables like `m`, no case can be identified, but if used with grammatical constructs, it should be **genitive**. Example from Euclid's algorithm:

> Bilde den Rest der ersten Variable modulo der zweiten Variable!

Comment: Interessant übrigens, dass sich bei Deinem letzten Beispiel auch die Frage stellt, ob man „Variable“ als substantiviertes Adjektiv deklinieren möchte („der Variablen“).

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Das ist meine ganz eigene Ignoranz.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if I am an expert, but I am a German mathematician. I would use the genitive case.

Comment: Achso, wunderbar, dann kann ich dich vielleicht fragen, ob auch *modulo* etwa für $S^{n-1} \cong SO(n)/SO(n-1)$ geläufig ist. Oder sagt man dort *durch*?

Comment: Gute Frage, ich bin mir ehrlich gesagt nicht ganz sicher. Ich glaube, ich würde „nach“ oder deutlicher „faktorisiert nach“ sagen, aber andere mögen das anders halten.

Comment: Achso, dann vielleicht ist die ganze Frage da oben nur Unfug vom Anfang an. :/

Comment: Auf jeden Fall Genitiv ;)

Comment: Der Genitiv ist in Ordnung, aber am geläufigsten ist mir hier der Nominativ. Dabei wird, was auch immer modulo genommen wird, als undeklinierbare Einheit betrachtet (so ähnlich manchmal wie Titel von Werken in Anführungszeichen), also z. B.: »F modulo [die symmetrische Gruppe]«, oder (Labor-Slang): »Das Ergebnis ist 2,53409 modulo Vorzeichen.«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, richtig, „modulo Vorzeichens“ würde ich auch nicht sagen, aber immer „modulo der Tatsache...“.