# "Thanks to" in German

Tags: preposition

As far as I know, the most common German preposition for "thanks to" is **dank + Genitive**.

But according to this [online dictionary](http://www.dict.cc/), the preposition [*dank*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=dank) can equally take the dative case:

> dank *deiner* = thanks to you

and

> dank *dir* = thanks to you

If this is so, are there any differences between the two ways in which **dank** can be used?

Comment: What does "G" in "dank + G" mean? Please never use abbreviations without explanation! Please edit you post and write the whole word.

Comment: "dank deiner" is not "thanks to you", it's "because of your", as in "dank deiner Hilfe" being "because of / with your help".

Comment: `dank deiner` has to be followed by an object to make sense. It's equal to `Thanks to your...`. Example `Dank deiner` **`schnellen Hilfe`** `bin ich jetzt viel früher fertig`. You could also say `Dank dir bin ich jetzt viel schneller fertig` which puts the focus more on the person responsible than on the action.

Comment: @Robert. This is exactly what "thanks to you" means in English. You are constructing a false contrast between German and English usage.

Comment: @fdb Read again. Genitive. I changed the translation just to make it clearer, and because I find it more idiomatic.

Comment: `Danke deiner` does *not* need an object if `deiner` is not a possessive pronoun but the genitive of the personal pronoun `du`. This usage is very rare, but grammatically orthodox.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, *dank* has always been followed by the dative.

However, there is a general opinion that the genitive is slowly supplanted by the dative. In trying to counteract the demise of the genitive, many people erroneously use it where the dative would have been correct.

---

Addendum concerning the etymology of "dank":

> **dank**  Präp.   ‘infolge, wegen’ (Ende 19. Jh.); voraus gehen Verbindungen des Substantivs mit Dativobjekten, *Dank (sei) jmdm., einer Sache*, die seit dem 18. Jh. ihren parenthetischen Charakter verlieren und zunehmend kausal verwendet werden.
>   
>   <sub>Quelle: „dank“, bereitgestellt durch das Digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/dank, abgerufen am 20.09.2017.</sub>

Comment: Hi. Perhaps "trotz" is a good example that can take both the genitive and the dative?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Actually *trotz* is the opposite of *dank*. *Trotz* for long time only allowed the genitive and now the frowned-upon dative spreads (at least colloquially), whereas bei dank it seems the other way round.

Comment: @guidot Hi. So "trotz allem" and "trotz alledem" are rare exceptions to the rule, then?

Comment: I tend to disagree with your first sentence. The Duden states otherwise: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dank

Comment: @Chaoskatze: The Duden only tells you how it is currently used and not what is gramatically correct or how the usage has developed. If people start to say "Ich danke dich." and do so over and over again, you may find it in a future edition of the Duden.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation. I understand your reasoning much better now. Could you add a word or two as to whether there is a difference between those two cases?

Answer (score 3):

According the [Pons dictionary](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=dank&l=dedx&in=&lf=), `dank` as preposition takes only the dative case but the [free dictionary](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/dank) says it takes either the dative or the genitive.

In order to understand this confusion, you can first read [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-is-german-really-losing-genitiv-evolutio?rq=1) about the condition of the Genitive case in the German language.

Briefly, I can say that the genitive is not as popular as it used to be. Because of this reason, you can hear / read `dank` with the dative case almost everywhere in contemporary texts and speeches.

I have always used *dank* with the dative case. I would also say *dank dir*.

Some examples of `dank` with the dative case:

> **Dank seinem Fleiß** hat er die Prüfung bestanden
>
> Das Kind erreichte das Ziel **dank seinem Vater**

Comment: For me, the entry that proposes the genitive after _dank_ in the free dictionary (http://de.thefreedictionary.com/dank) is invalid. The example sentence "_Sie konnte das Problem dank ihrer Erfahrung lösen_" can well be interpreted such that _dank_ is followed by the dative. Just replace _dank_ with _mit_, which is clearly dative, and you will see that it is still "_... ihrer Erfahrung ..._".

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich The examples are changed. I hope these new examples are better.

Comment: What do you mean? There is still the same example sentence as before at http://de.thefreedictionary.com/dank.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Which one do you mean? I have changed both examples.

Comment: Zitat: "dạnk Präp; mit Gen/Dat; verwendet, um den Grund für etwas meist Positives einzuleiten ≈ aufgrund: Sie konnte das Problem dank ihrer Erfahrung lösen"

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es tut mir leid. Ich verstehe nicht. Ich habe dieses Zitat, das du hier geschrieben hast, nicht als Beispiel in meiner Antwort geschrieben.  Verpasse ich vielleicht etwas?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es gibt zwei Beispiele: 

erste: **Dank seinem Fleiß hat er die Prüfung bestanden**

zweite: **Das Kind erreichte das Ziel dank seinem Vater**

Comment: Häh? Es geht um die Zitate unter http://de.thefreedictionary.com/dank. Aber das habe ich nun schon zum dritten mal geschrieben.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich habe es verstanden. Aber das Zitat auf der verlinkten Website hat nichts mit meiner Antwort zu tun. Ich habe "the free dictionary" verlinkt, um zu zeigen, dass ein Wörter sagt, dass *dank* genitiv oder dativ nimmt, ein anderes Wörterbuch sagt, dass es nur dativ nimmt.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, "dank" can be followed by either the dative or the genitive. (See [Duden/dank](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dank)) However, genitive is preferably used when "dank" is followed by a plural.

> Dank wissenschaftlichen Fortschritten stieg der Lebensstandard.

is therefore less common than

> Dank wissenschaftlicher Fortschritte stieg der Lebensstandard.

As for the question whether there is a difference between those two possibilities: No there is not. The meaning will stay the same.

Your examples are both correct, even though in spoken language the use of genitive may seem highly educated.