# Ein (gutes) Stück Wegs

Tags: grammatical-case, noun

This post is on *Wegs* as found in this excerpt from [Die zwei Brüder](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_zwei_Br%C3%BCder_(1857)) as collected by Brothers Grimm.

> Als der bestimmte Tag kam, schenkte der Pflegevater jedem eine gute Büchse und einen Hund und ließ jeden von seinen gesparten Goldstücken nehmen, soviel er wollte. Darauf begleitete er sie ein Stück **Wegs**, und beim Abschied gab er ihnen noch ein blankes Messer und sprach:

Also you can find several instances *ein gutes Stück Wegs* on this [Web page](http://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/St%C3%BCck+Wegs).

**QUESTION**

1. Which case is *Wegs* in?  (E.g. the genitive.)
2. If it is not in the genitive, how can we account for the *s* at the end?
3. Am I right to think that normally German uses apposition to express quantity, as in:

   > ein bisschen Käse
4. Is it also acceptable to say (on the model of *ein Stück Wegs*):

   > ein bisschen Käses
5. Can we put *ein bisschen Käse* into the genitive?  For example, we might have occasion to say *einem bisschen Käse*, where both nouns are in the dative. But can we have:

   > eines bisschens Käses
6. How could one say *a piece of the table* (it has broken off).  Could it be one of:

   > ein Stück des Tisches
   > ein Stück von dem Tisch
7. If *ein Stück Wegs* is a set phrase and I should not try to generalize from it, are there other set phrases that look like it?

What I would have really liked to say is: 'Please explain what's going on with *Wegs* as against related usages.'  I tried to break that down as above.

Comment: It is an abbreviated writing for "ein Stück des Weges", hence Genitive.

Comment: It is always dangerous to try to fit centuries old texts into modern grammar rules. 1) They are old and might use outdated rules. 2) As they are (almost) always "art", authors often tend to bend their contemporary rules to begin with (to create a better "flow" of the text etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Stück](https://www.dwds.de/wb/St%C3%BCck)

Among other possible meanings for *Stück* a piece of a whole is meant in this case. In German it asks for genitive case:

> Ein Stück des Ganzen. Ein Stück des Weg(e)s. Ein Stück seines Lebens.

If however this piece became a whole thing by itself we can see that *Stück* turns into a counter for the object:

> Ein Stück des Kuchens *becomes* ein Stück Kuchen
> Ein Stück des Käses *becomes* ein Stück Käse
> Ein Stück des Weges *usually does not result in a single countable piece because we can not cut the way into pieces.*

Note that in recent years [the genitive case is vanishing](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7207/der-dativ-ist-dem-genitiv-sein-tod-is-german-really-losing-genitiv-evolutio) not only in colloquial speech but also in written text to be replaced by dative case. This would then lead to a correct but lower style alternative:

> Ein Stück von dem Weg. Ein Stück von dem Käse.

Comment: Das verlinkte Posting thematisiert zwar das angebliche Verschwinden des Genitivs, bleibt aber jeden Nachweis schuldig. Als Zeitzeuge höre ich jetzt seit 30 Jahren, dass der Genitiv verschwindet - nie war er gesünder als heute. Und im Ggs. zum Hochhaussturz ("schon 99 Stockwerke - noch ist nichts passiert!") verschwindet er ja sicher nicht schlagartig.

Comment: It would be useful to mention the technical term *partitiver Genitiv* in this otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both "ein Stück von dem Tisch" as "ein Stück des Tisches" would be grammatically correct or at least used, however I am not sure about your Käse example.

Comment: „Er begleitete mich ein Stück Weg” sounds wrong to me. This is probably because the expression has become rigid over time (it is now a fixed expression, using its old grammar form “ein Stück + genitive”) and cannot be bound to the more (presumably) recent switch to “ein Stück + Akkusativ”.